# How to use a google doc / excel spreadsheet to calculate custom pricing?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, shopify

I am just beginning to use Shopify and sell custom sized products. I have a google spreadsheet that I use to input the dimensions to calculate the price.

I need to use Length, Width, and Height in nearly infinite combinations to calculate the price for custom products.

I would like to make this kind of functionality available on my shopify site.

How would I go about doing this?

Thank you!

Darran

Comment: Prices for products are fixed, you can't calculate them, at least with the way you describe it. If you need to calculate prices  you will need something like Shopify Scripts ( which is a Shopify Plus App ) and use Ruby logic to modify the prices. Please provide more information what exactly you like to calculate and why can't use use Shopify variants instead.

Answer (score 1):

I have been doing that since Shopify began. Take your complex spreadsheet and either figure out a price per unit measure, or you can install a custom App that maps the measurements to a variant. With a Proxy callback securely sending the customers desired measurements to the App, it will choose the correct variant and hence pricing for the measures.

Nothing is infinite! You have to set some limits. And yes, Plus allows for scripting, but it is not ideal, and can be quite difficult to build out a fast and accurate pricing machine. A big strike against that approach is the fact that your customer would not know pricing till checkout, not exactly friendly commerce!

Comment: Looking into how to do this. Will report back. Thank you!